# Delphi Berlin: Why Icon Application and Launch Image do not work on iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, delphi, ios-simulator, firemonkey

I'm defining the images for the app icon and the splash screen (iOS Simulator platform - iOS 10.1) as indicated in Project || Options -> Application.
All images are correctly indicated in deployament and are being updated, but when running the application in iOS Simulator, the icon image and launch image are not updated and the default firemonkey icon is shown.
Anyone have any idea what might be happening?
Thanks.

Comment: Try deleting the app from the device, then redeploy

Comment: This is expected to work in the simulator, so more information (eg: pointer to your project) will be needed for us to help you.

Comment: Hi Dave and Jeremy,  I customized the info.plist file and needed to update the file with the images. Thanks!